# Paypal Token error

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-rest-sdk

I am setting up a Paypal Subscription - first I create the Token, my example coding can be seen here:

```
function testing(){

     $urltoken = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";

           $header_token = array(
               'Accept'=>'application/json',
               'Accept-Language'=>'en_US',

           );

           $request_body_token = array(
               'client_id'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
               'secret'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
               'grant_type'=>'client_credentials',



           );

             $take_from_token = wp_remote_request($urltoken, array('method' => 'POST', 'timeout' => 20, 'headers' => $header_token,'body'=>$request_body_token)); 

             var_dump($take_from_token);
```

}

This is the Response error that I get:

```
array(5) { ["headers"]=> array(8) { ["server"]=> string(17) "Apache-Coyote/1.1" ["proxy_server_info"]=> string(57) "host=slcsbplatformapiserv3001.slc.paypal.com;threadId=850" ["paypal-debug-id"]=> string(13) "09c6fcdc16b91" ["server_info"]=> string(139) "identitysecuretokenserv:v1.oauth2.token&CalThreadId=133&TopLevelTxnStartTime=14c459ad0be&Host=slcsbidensectoken502.slc.paypal.com&pid=28506" ["date"]=> string(29) "Mon, 23 Mar 2015 07:48:35 GMT" ["content-type"]=> string(16) "application/json" ["content-length"]=> string(2) "75" ["connection"]=> string(5) "close" } ["body"]=> string(75) "{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Invalid client credentials"}" ["response"]=> array(2) { ["code"]=> int(401) ["message"]=> string(12) "Unauthorized" } ["cookies"]=> array(0) { } ["filename"]=> NULL }
```

Comment: did you check if your `client_id` is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the parameter 'mode' to 'live'. If this is set to default then it uses 'sandbox' and it can't use the live credentials.

Otherwise try running this test via cURL:

```
curl -v -u "client_id:test" "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token" -X POST -d "response_type=token&grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Remember to replace the client id (test in the above) with your own.